# Is it possible to build an XCode project within command line in CentOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line

I'm creating an app that can be purchased and personalised so the buyer can have their own app to upload to the app store. I want to be able to automate the personalisation, and I was wondering if it's possible to build and app over command line in CentOS? I know it's possible in OS X, but other unix systems?

Comment: For the app store an app needs to be signed, and you can only do this on OS X AFAIK, so even if you could get all the other tools to work the signing would be a deal-breaker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what about if I had a OS X Server, is it possible to do it over command line then and still have it signed?

Comment: Anything you can do locally on Mac OS X you can do remotely, so yes, you could ssh into a Mac OS X build machine and build/sign apps remotely that way.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if it's possible to build and app over command line in
>   CentOS? I know it's possible in OS X, but other unix systems?

Yes. The [iphone-dev](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Portability) teams appears to have ported to CentOS 4.

The folks who work on Cydia use Debian based systems for their development, so I would expect other linux derivatives to be available. The Cydia folks even bake in apt-get and a repo for the device.

[Jailbreak QA](http://www.jailbreakqa.com), [Upgrading the iPhone Toolchain](http://www.saurik.com/id/4), [iphone-dev Portability](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Portability), and [Bringing Debian APT to the iPhone](http://www.saurik.com/id/1) would probably be helpful to you.